# Extbase: Make two forms on a same page modifying same object have separate validation errors and user input

Tags: validation, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a `Parent` object, which has a `$children` property of type `ObjectStorage`, which holds collection of `Child` objects.

Page contains two Fluid forms, pointed to a same `saveAction()`, whether 1st form accepts a file-upload (CSV-file) for `$children` property, and 2nd form accepts list of inputs.

Simplified it looks like this:

```
<f:form action="save" name="parent" object="{parent}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <f:form.validationResults for="parent">
    error output
    </f:form.validationResults>
    <f:form.upload property="children" />
    <f:form.submit />
</f:form>

<f:form action="save" name="parent" object="{parent}">
    <f:form.validationResults for="parent">
    error output
    </f:form.validationResults>
    <f:form.textfield property="children.0.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.1.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.2.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.3.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.4.title" />
    <f:form.submit />
</f:form>
```

Both forms are creating child objects for parent.

All works good except the case, when validation error appears (file format wrong, title of child is incorrect, etc.). Then validation errors are shown in both forms, regardless from which one was submitted. Also parsed titles from CSV-file are shown in inputs of 2nd form.

I can see a reason of this: request parameter `parent` is taken from form's name and it is same for both of them. But if I rename it in one of the forms, PropertyMapper will no longer find an action variable to map the renamed property to.

I've found, that property mapping configuration allows to set mapping for properties, so I've changed the `<f:form.upload property="children" />` to `<f:form.upload property="childrenFile" />` and then set a mapping in `initializeSaveAction()`:

```
$this->arguments['parent']
    ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
    ->setMapping('childrenFile', 'children');
```

But it only helps the Property Mapper to identify the target property name, and all the validation results are still shown under `<f:form.validationResults for="parent.children">`, not under `parent.childrenFile` as I was expecting.

The only dirty solution I see now is to have two different actions (and so different form `name` attributes) with different argument names, but which are actually doing same.

This solves a problem in a simple case, but in more sophisticated cases (e.g. relying on argument being always named `parent` and have a logic based on it, like access check) it becomes complicated and still looks like a dirty solution.

Is there a clean way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the object and action of one form, then you can access the validation errors seperatly.

```
<f:form action="saveUpload" name="uploadParent" object="{parent}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <f:form.validationResults for="uploadParent">
    error output
    </f:form.validationResults>
    <f:form.upload property="children" />
    <f:form.submit />
</f:form>

<f:form action="save" name="parent" object="{parent}">
    <f:form.validationResults for="parent">
    error output
    </f:form.validationResults>
    <f:form.textfield property="children.0.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.1.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.2.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.3.title" />
    <f:form.textfield property="children.4.title" />
    <f:form.submit />
</f:form>
```

now you need an new action:

```
protected function saveUploadAction(Object $uploadParent) {
  $this->forward('save', NULL, NULL, array('parent' => $uploadParent));
}
```

ofcourse: your validation should also in the new saveUploadAction, so the error comes from the first action before the forward is make.

Comment: That's what I came to as workaround. Which is acceptable, but still not clean solution :)

Comment: "a clean solution" would be to make the two forms to one ;)